How do we know that we can't directly solve Kepler's equation?
I'm learning about Kepler's equation $M=E-e \sin E$, and keep bumping into various statements like: "Kepler's equation is a transcendental equation and so cannot be inverted and solved directly for E". Example here.
My understanding is that some transcendental equations can be transformed into algebraic equations. How do we know that Kepler's equation is not one of these?

@YvesDaoust  It has finitely many real solutions, but infinitely many complex solutions.  That leaves open the possibility of a transformation such as $E = \sqrt{ c - z^2}$ that is real for $z$ in a certain interval of reals but imaginary for real $z$ outside of that interval.
